# Why do I get a reference error: conn is not defined when I attempt to create a table or add content to a table in rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb

New install of rethinkdb.  I have tried to used the data explorer to to populate a table but get an error message: conn is not defined.

I tried to reinstall rethinkdb but same results. I cannot find instructions to completely uninstall rethinkdb.  Running on Ubuntu

Comment: Why don't you simply create a conn?